# Can JSON return html of a partial view

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a main view which renders a set of partial views. One partial view is rendered if a condition is met. When the condition is not met a button is displayed.

When this button is clicked I want to inject the html of the partial view into the page using Ajax. Is there a way I can do this? Something like

`return Json("partialViewName');`

or

`return Json(GetHTMLFromPartialView("partialViewName"));`

You can inject html using Ajax. Can I somehow use the html from a partial view instead of writing all the lines of code in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

If I get this correctly, You can use

```
if( true) // condition met 
{
  return Json(....);
}
else
{
  retrun PartialView(..)
}
```

Comment: Ok.. So you have a partial view and you want to compile and get the html out of it ? My this understanding correct?

Comment: I don't need the html at compile time. I need the html when a button is pressed. If it is not possible then that's also an answer...anyone??

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.nikolay-angelov.eu/asp-net-mvc-reuse-partial-views-in-ajax/) any other idea's are welcome